# Error occored in include file due to incorrect way of including(may be) or some thing?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, sqlite, ipad

I'm developing an iPad application and I'm including **libsqlite3.dylib** file from path

**/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/lib**

and importing  in my .h files.. still i get following error:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:144:0 Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'extern' in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h
```

can any one sort it out why is it happening, and please give the solution..
thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are importing some Obj-C++ headers that cannot be compiled directly against your Obj-C code. You need to do one of the following -

- rename the class file you are importing into, from ".m" to ".mm".
- change the file type of the class file you are importing into, from objc to cpp.objc (right click on the file in group tree - get info - file type)

That should tell the compiler to compile your class as ObjC-Cpp.